# Is it possible to login to a site from actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript

Lets say I've written a flash program that sends POST requests to a web site. Then if the web server sets cookies or sessions, how can I get those cookies/session variable names, lets say that the server uses PHP.

Some little example of code please. Just for view.

Comment: from a desctop flash program to a web site

Comment: Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231693/post-login-with-actionscript-2-0

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109580/how-do-i-access-cookies-within-flash). There's a solution how to grab the cookie data.